# Why is it Autism Spectrum Disorder and not Autism Disorder Spectrum?

Tags: word-order

Certainly with Disorder trailing behind "Autism Spectrum" it indicates that the disorder is called *Autism Spectrum* when spectrum is merely being used to describe that the disorder has a spectrum. *Billy is on the Autism Disorder Spectrum* **vs** *Billy has the Autism Spectrum Disorder*

Comment: Because it's "Autism Spectrum Disorder" in the DSM-5.

Comment: (And it would be "Billy has **an** Autism Spectrum Disorder.")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Autism Spectrum" consists of a number of disorders which appear to lie along a continuous "spectrum" from mild to severe.  There are various severities of outright autism, plus what was once called Asperger's disease (now a blip on the ASD spectrum) and even milder conditions that are starting to look like ADHD.

So a person does not "have Autism Spectrum Disorder" (since "Autism Spectrum Disorder is not a single distinct disorder), but instead "has a disorder on the Autism Spectrum", or "has an Autism Spectrum Disorder".

Comment: More and more I come across the expression: "to be on the spectrum", as a shorter version.

Answer (score 0):

***ASD Autism Spectrum Disorder*** is a condition that affects the Neuro-developmental ability of a person.

**ASD has wide-ranging levels of severity and characteristics of the autistic spectrum whose cause is not well understood.**

The term is referred to as Autism Spectrum Disorder as it includes **autism, Asperger’s syndrome, sensory integration disorder and pervasive developmental disorder not otherwise specified (PPD-NOS).**

A person on the autism spectrum has difficulties in some areas of their development, but other skills may develop typically.
Individuals on this spectrum have different traits and signs.

***Personal Note:*** I work as a tutor at **Accel for children and adults with autism spectrum** and have experienced that no two individuals have a similar persona. They have their own way of opening up to others and getting comfortable with the environment. You have to be a bit careful as not to offend anyone.

Individuals on the autism spectrum, mainly face difficulties while making social communication and interaction and show repetitive behavior.